# Monitor not displaying fully

Tags: windows-10, display, vga

I am using a VA1931wma LED monitor connected using a VGA cable.

[image]

As you can see, I'm running Windows 10 and the screen has gone inside, and the right side is completely blanked out black.

I have been using 1366x768 resolution for a couple of years and today it is behaving like this. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see on your photo, the resolution seems to be correct. You have to realign the picture on the monitor device. Often called *"adjust"*

See the [manual](http://www.viewsoniceurope.com/asset-files/files/user_guide/va1931wma-led/18071.pdf) on how to do this. 
(It says `Button 2` is a shortcut for auto adjust)